# Apache causes 403 forbidden even when using DocumentRoot that is working with other domain

Tags: apache, webserver, ubuntu-16.04

```
wget http://maydomain.example

--2017-04-06 18:21:12--  https://mydomain.example
Resolving mydomain.example (mydomain.example)... IP
Connecting to mydomain.example (mydomain.example)|IP|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2017-04-06 18:21:12 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

But other domain (at `http://OTHER.example`) is working, so I changed `DocumentRoot` to OTHER and (after restart apache2) the error was the same!

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin suporte@mydomain.example
    ServerName mydomain.example
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.example
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/OTHER.example

   # DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain.example

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

#?? Require all granted
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.oficial.news [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =oficial.news
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

The files `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomain.example.conf` and `/etc/apache2/sites-available/OTHER.example.conf` diffs only by filenames and the domain names into its confs.

---

### Notes

May be... rewrite or `.access` at parent folder?

```
more /var/www/html/.htaccess

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: This looks like issue with SSL configuration. Can you share details of file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf`?

Comment: Thanks for the file. It looks like you have only one virtual host listening on port 443. Do you have separate `<VirtualHost *:443>` configuration for your subdomains? Or does calling ` wget http:/OTHER.example` also redirect to `https`?
Also have you tried setting `Loglevel debug`, and tailing `${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log`? You may get some clues from there.

Comment: Hi @Nomad, I using "all as default"... But another information: we installed, at `/var/www/html` a [Wordpress Multisite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Multisite), and for SSL using certbot (lets encrypt for all domains and subdomains)... For logs, etc. thanks, I will check today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was the configuration of the virtual host... See the `Rewrite*` lines, I removed all,

```
# REMOVED THIS:
# RewriteEngine on
# RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.oficial.news [OR]
# RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =oficial.news   
# RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
```

now is working (!).

Thanks @Nomad and   @MatíasNavarroCarter for clues and checklists.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that you're using some Debian derivative (maybe Ubuntu 16.04) to work for your dev enviroment. I've done this many times.

What causes your error is probably that the var/www/html folder is "rooted". That means, root owns it, and Apache (www-data user) doesn't have the enough permissions to access that content. There are several solutions to this. You can choose what fits your needs the most. I'm going to post my preferred one first:

1. **Work with Virtual Hosts:** Working in localhost may be good for some. I prefer to use virtualhosts ended in .dev. Then, I point the document root to a folders project I have, more accessible than the localhost. I [created a script](https://gist.github.com/mnavarrocarter/2e10e6986437ea1a6b826b71282bdaf9) to easily do all that.
2. **Change the permissions of `/var/www/html`:** Chown that folder to be of the www-data user and www-group, and chmod it 777. Warning: make sure when you upload it to your production server that permissions are ok.
3. **Change Apache user to root:** Of all these, this is my least recommended, but it works.

Comment: Hi, yes, using UBUNTU 16LTS. Another context: the /var/www/html is with [Wordpress Multisite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Multisite)... The permissions there are all ok, was the first check.. It is also a Virtual Host... I'll be back tomorrow after some tests,

Comment: So change the Apache user to be your user. You can do this with: 

1. `sudo nano /etc/apache2/envvars`

2. Change apache run user and group (www-data) with your username. But don't do this if your server is for production.